# Not able to run Kafka Connect in distributed mode - Error while attempting to create/ find topics 'connect-offsets'

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

> [2017-08-31 10:15:20,715] WARN The configuration
>   'internal.key.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:20,715] WARN The configuration
>   'status.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known
>   config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231)
>   [2017-08-31 10:15:20,715] WARN The configuration
>   'internal.value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a
>   known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231)
>   [2017-08-31 10:15:20,715] WARN The configuration
>   'value.converter.schemas.enable' was supplied but isn't a known
>   config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231)
>   [2017-08-31 10:15:20,715] WARN The configuration
>   'internal.value.converter' was supplied but isn't a known config.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:20,715] WARN The configuration
>   'offset.storage.replication.factor' was supplied but isn't a known
>   config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231)
>   [2017-08-31 10:15:20,716] WARN The configuration
>   'offset.storage.topic' was supplied but isn't a known config.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:20,716] WARN The configuration 'value.converter' was supplied
>   but isn't a known config.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:20,716] WARN The configuration 'key.converter' was supplied but
>   isn't a known config.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig:231) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:20,768] INFO jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:327) Aug 31, 2017 10:15:21 AM
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors WARNING: The following
>   warnings have been detected: WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   listConnectors in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource
>   contains empty path annotation. WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   createConnector in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorsResource
>   contains empty path annotation. WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   listConnectorPlugins in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.ConnectorPluginsResource
>   contains empty path annotation. WARNING: The (sub)resource method
>   serverInfo in
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.resources.RootResource contains
>   empty path annotation.
>
> [2017-08-31 10:15:21,142] INFO Started
>   o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@63f02de0{/,null,AVAILABLE}
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler:744) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:21,149] INFO Started
>   ServerConnector@61b06738{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8083}
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector:266) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:21,149] INFO Started @13584ms
>   (org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server:379) [2017-08-31 10:15:21,150] INFO
>   REST server listening at http://172.28.193.126:8083/, advertising URL
>   http://172.28.193.126:8083/
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer:150) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:21,150] INFO Kafka Connect started
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect:55) [2017-08-31
>   10:15:21,468] ERROR Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:206)
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while
>   attempting to create/find topic(s) 'connect-offsets'  at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:245)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore$1.run(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog.start(KafkaBasedLog.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore.start(KafkaOffsetBackingStore.java:109)
>     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.start(Worker.java:146)   at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.startServices(AbstractHerder.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.run(DistributedHerder.java:194)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownServerException: The server
>   experienced an unexpected error when processing the request   at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.util.TopicAdmin.createTopics(TopicAdmin.java:226)

Comment: What version of Kafka Connect, and what version of Kafka? What is your Connect worker configuration?

Comment: kafka-connect 3.3.0 and kafka 0.10.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka Connect 0.11.0.0 cannot create the topics on brokers older than 0.10.1.0, since the protocol used in those older brokers do not support topic management.

So, if you have an older broker, you should either manually create the topics or rely upon broker auto-creation. Unfortunately, [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5704) in Kafka Connect 0.11.0.0 prevents auto-creation, and so until 0.11.0.1 is available you will have to manually create the topics.

Answer (score 4):

When starting up Kafka Connect in distributed mode, it will try to create or expect several topics to be present in Kafka. In my case auto topic creation had been turned off so Kafka Connect could not create topics in the environment I was running it in. Creating these topics myself solved the issue. You would have specified the names of these topics in your properties file (below).

`offset.storage.topic`

`config.storage.topic`

`status.storage.topic`