# Kafka connect REST Api crashing when I GET the /connectors route

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm currently working on deploying the Kafka connect cluster on a 3 nodes cluster.
My cluster is a cloudera (version 5.x) with a kerberos set up.

Before trying Kafka connect, I managed to set up a topic that I used with a producer and consumer console implementation. I thought it could be relevant to precise that this worked in the past.

I came across this error :

> ERROR Uncaught exception in herder work thread, exiting:  (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:228)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition connect-offsets-0 could be determined

After looking for similar issues I found that some people manage to make it work by setting the topics `connect-status`, `connect-offsets`, `connect-configs`.

Which I did like:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic connect-status --zookeeper address:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic connect-offsets --zookeeper address:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic connect-configs --zookeeper address:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

It didn't work for me and also even if it would have work, I'm a bit surprised that setting those topics with a `partitions` of `1` could be acceptable in production, it can't be the end solution no ?

What can I do ?

EDIT: So I just ran the kafka connect in distributed mode again without trying to reach the /connectors route and it crashed anyway.

References:

[Not able to run Kafka Connect in distributed mode - Error while attempting to create/ find topics 'connect-offsets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987021/not-able-to-run-kafka-connect-in-distributed-mode-error-while-attempting-to-cr)

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/189

Comment: Regardless of replication, those topics should not be one partition. Is that the only error in the logs?

Comment: it was the only error yes

Comment: Well, a timeout would tell me that the bootstrap servers or security settings are incorrect. You could also modify the log4j.properties to get more log output

Comment: I got it working by using another version of kafka 2.7 (vs 2.1 or something) in a folder where I have all the permission.

Comment: Okay, well connect and the brokers don't need to be the same version (and shouldn't be on the same machines anyway), so just run it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's some hack from CDH team to have only one partition for these topics. But if you will setup `--replication-factor` to `3` there is no danger that you will lost Kafka Connect configuration/offset/status for you connectors when the leader will fail.